# TFS 2010 TF30065 An unhandled exception occurred

Tags: team-foundation-server

I have Install new instance of sql server in the server and Now the TFS2010 not working with error :

> TF30065 An unhandled exception occurred

I can't found the real error to fix it, how I know the error detail or how I fix this ! there's many project in it and I have to fix it

thank you for any suggestion

edit : I found the error log of the error

Message d'exception :

> Échec du chargement du fichier Msxmlsql.dll. L'instruction préparée
>   avec le handle 0 est introuvable. sp_xml_removedocument : la valeur
>   fournie pour le paramètre numéro 1 n'est pas valide.
>   WIN-Server\SQLEXPRESS.Tfs_Configuration..prc_QueryCatalogNodes:
>   Database Statement Failure - Error %error="8179";% executing INSERT
>   statement for @pathSpec L'instruction a été arrêtée. (type
>   SqlException)

Comment: Can you still connect to the original instance via SQL Server Management Studio? Are the databases still there?

Comment: @ChrisMcKeown yes I can connect to the original database, I have the first sql V 10.1. and I installed V 10.50.1600 and the two work fine

Comment: Did you reboot after the installation completed?  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/941105

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have remove the second sql instance but the same error, then I have upgrade the first instnace from 10.0 to 10.50 the same of the new instance installed and it work now